# Vue select list rendering before getting data from Meteor callback

Tags: javascript, meteor, callback, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to populate my events array from a meteor call so it shows up in a select list. The Meteor function 'get.upcoming' returns an array of JSON objects, but I think the select list is rendered before the event array gets populated.

Is there a way to re-render the select box or render it only after the events array gets populated?

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <select v-model='eventId'>
            <option v-for='event in events'>{{JSON.stringify(event)}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                eventId: "",
                events: [],
            }
        },

        created() {
            this.getItems();
        },

        methods: {
            getItems() {
                console.log("getting items");
                Meteor.call('get.upcoming', function(err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        events = res;
                        console.log(events);
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.events = res;` in your Meteor call callback function to save the response to `events`.

Also, use an arrow function for your callback so that it can access the Vue instance via `this`.

```
getItems() {
  console.log('getting items');
  Meteor.call('get.upcoming', (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      this.events = res;
      console.log(this.events);
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To rerender the select box, simply just setting the data array which is two-way binded to the select box will rerender the given select box. All registered variables in the `data()` method in a Vue template definition are available as template class variables once the web page loads, with its contents optionally two-way binded to components.

`if (!error) this.events = newEvents`

2. If you would like to show the select box only after the JSON objects will be received from the Meteor method and populated into the events array, then simply set a Vue conditional binding to a boolean to show the HTML DOM element after the data is loaded.

```html
<template>
  <select v-if="dataLoaded"> </select>
</template>

<script>
return {
  data() {
    return {
      dataLoaded: false
    }
  }

  asyncMethod() { this.dataLoaded = true; }
};
</script>
```